# Why do we return root?

Tags: python, tree

I have always just blindly returned the root during these tree recursion problems without asking why. I have an idea that its about keeping the consitency or order of the tree. What is `return root` returning to? It makes sense that at the last step we are returning root after all the recursions, but why is it neccessary for the intermediate recursions?

I have chosen the simple LC 226 problem that tries to invert a Binary Tree:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def invertTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        
        if root == None:
            return root
        
        root.left,root.right=root.right,root.left

        self.invertTree(root.left)
        self.invertTree(root.right)

        return root
```

I couldn't find a definite answer online.

Comment: "why is it neccessary for the intermediate recursions" - do you *know* you're at an intermediate level?

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to that. What I meant was that why is it necessary to return root during recursion of the subtrees.

Comment: Okay, say you want to not `return root` when you're handling a subtree. How are you going to write the code to do that? Do you see an option that's actually *cleaner* than just returning `root` all the time?

Comment: I'm asking why are we returning root at each step of the recursion.  I'm not arguing about finding an implementation that is cleaner than returning root.

Comment: You're returning `root` at every step because you wrote the code that way. You could have chosen not to do that, and it'd be fine, though it'd take a bit of extra code.

Comment: When you call it recursively, `root` is the root of a sub-tree, not the root of the whole tree. How about naming it `top`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought that returning the root was actually doing something in the intermedite recursions. It's only useful at the end. Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

In your algorithm, the recursive call return value is totally ignored:

```py
self.invertTree(root.left)  # no = operator
self.invertTree(root.right)  # no = operator
```

Only the top-level client code may choose to use the return value of `return root`, which in this case is the LeetCode testing suite. It wouldn't need to use the return value if it called the function in a strictly [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) manner:

```py
root = TreeNode(...)  # some tree input
Solution.invertTree(root)
# assert some properties of root, newly inverted in-place
```

Instead, it's (presumably) using the return value:

```py
root = TreeNode(...)  # some tree input
result = Solution.invertTree(root)
# assert some properties of result, even though `result is root` is true
```

If it's clearer, you can write a separate function that performs the in-place tree manipulation, then use a wrapper function to return the result to the caller:

```py
class Solution:
    def invertTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: TreeNode
        """
        def invert(root):
            if root:
                root.left, root.right = root.right, root.left
                invert(root.left)
                invert(root.right)

        invert(root)
        return root
```

In the above code, `invert` could just as easily be a static class function rather than an inner function. Same idea. It's generally confusing when in-place functions also return a value. In the Python standard library, in-place methods usually don't return a value. `list.sort()` is a good example of a well-designed in-place method since it returns `None`, avoiding subtle bugs where the client assumes the method is pure and returns a copy, which is usually the contract implication when functions and methods return a value.

Long story short: part of the reason you're confused is because LeetCode has given you a poorly-designed method to write.

As an aside, LeetCode should follow PEP-8 and `snake_case` their function. There's also no point in this being an instance method. It should be either a static class function or operate on `self.root` rather than a parameter `root`.